# Change/ edit the display of the sender name

Tags: vba, outlook

I had converted ost file to pst.

The converter changed the sender name as --
`Firstname Surname<email id>`
i.e. without space after the surname and bracket.

Email address in my system has space between surname and <.
`Firstname Surname <email id>`

I need to change/ edit the sender name with the space because I am not able find duplicate emails.

Answer (score 0):

The MailItem.SenderName property is read-only, so you'll have to change the PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME_W MAPI property using [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) to do it:

```
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

Set objEmail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set objPA = objEmail.PropertyAccessor
'PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME_W
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001F
objPA.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001F", "Stack Overflow Rocks!"
objEmail.Save
```